# Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION'

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am building a ionic project and getting this error

> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>   Error: /Users/lalitkushwah/Desktop/BuildForIOS/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Build file '/Users/lalitkushwah/Desktop/BuildForIOS/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 262
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>     Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

This is package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "trade-king-front-end",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
        "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.12.2",
        "@ionic-native/header-color": "^4.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/navigation-bar": "^4.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-headercolor": "^1.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-navigationbar": "^1.0.31",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "json2csv": "^4.2.1",
        "papaparse": "^4.6.0",
        "rxjs": "5.5.11",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
        "typescript": "~2.6.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-navigationbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-headercolor": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    } }
```

Thanks in advance if anyone have any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Change line in **project.properties** at platforms/android/project.properties from

cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-annotations:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION

to

cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+